# Node.js error trying to communicate via SSL to backend server

Tags: node.js, ssl

We operate a WebSocket server on Node.js 0.8.16, which very frequently receives telemetry messages from clients, which is routed to a backend server using regular HTTPS posts.

After a random period of time, we notice communication will fail to the telemetry service (even though another backend server is fine),

```
Error: 1240:error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:1234:SSL alert number 48
at CleartextStream._pusher (tls.js:656:24)
at SlabBuffer.use (tls.js:199:18)
at CleartextStream.CryptoStream._push (tls.js:483:33)
at SecurePair.cycle (tls.js:880:20)
at EncryptedStream.CryptoStream.write (tls.js:267:13)
at Socket.ondata (stream.js:38:26)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
at TCP.onread (net.js:397:14)
```

There don't appear to be a lot of community experience with such errors
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/3YYAmGNq4NM

was wondering if anybody encountered something similar, symptoms as mentioned in the post include a multitude of opened and pending FIN_WAIT_2 sockets on port 443.

The maxSockets property for http and https globalAgent had been set to 20000, but that didn't truly help even when there are way less number of connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update on the situation, I forked the underlying HTTP client library we were using - Restler - in order to tweak it to quit using connection pooling.

Have not experienced said problem ever since for months.